# Problem of configuring Omnet++ in windows OS

Tags: omnet++

I am facing trouble regarding configuring Omnet++ in the windows operating system. Every time I want to configure using the

```
./configure
```

command it shows an error message that no acceptable C compiler found in `$PATH`. I have already set the path of MinGW GCC compiler at the environment variable section under advanced system settings in my Windows but still, the problem doesn't resolve. Please help me in this regard.
For your convenience, I hereby attached an image of the aforementioned problem.

Error

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you edit your question and add your error as text, not image? External links may be death after some time, and a picture makes impossible to search text inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following steps:

1. Make sure you have downloaded `OMNeT++` for Windows, not for Linux nor MAC OS.
2. Extract the package using `7zip`.
3. Extract the package to the directory whose name does not contain a space.
4. Temporary turn off real-time antivirus protection.

Adding a path to system variable is not necessary for Windows version of `OMNeT++` because MinGW has already all paths.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect 2. and 4. is the problem here. The built-in windows extractor sometimes fails to extract the ZIP file properly.